# Is there a difference between the support and the support space of a d-dimensional complex matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Given $A \in M_d(\mathbb C)$ where $M_d(\mathbb C)$ denotes the d-dimensional complex valued matrices, I understand the support of $A$ as $ \mathrm{supp}(A) = \{v \in \mathbb C^d | Av \neq 0\}$ i.e $\mathrm{ supp} A) = (\mathrm{ker}(A))^{\perp}$.

In a proof I am trying to follow, the support space of $A$ is mentioned, and via the context it seems as if the support space is contained within $M_d(\mathbb C)$. Is there a difference between the support of $A$ (contained within $\mathbb C^d$) and the support space of A? If so, how does one define the support space of $A$?